# multiple datasets normalized in a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two different datasets and I want to normalize them (by subtracting the individual median). Then I want to show them in a single scatter plot but in different colors.

```
normalize <- function(y) {
  y - median(y)
}

x1  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
x2  <- seq(-3, 3, 0.10)
y1 <- normalize(pnorm(x1)-3)
y2 <- normalize(pnorm(x2))
```

But the main problem is the combination of the data for the plot

```
df <- data.frame(y1,y2)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=y1), colour="red") +
  geom_point(aes(y=y2), colour="green")
```

gives an error

```
Error in data.frame(y1, y2) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 81, 121
```

and I don't understand why the datasets would need to have the exact same number of rows to be plotted. How to draw these two different datasets into one plot?

Comment: It's not the plot that's the problem. It's your data frame. You are trying to put two vectors of different lengths into a data frame. Put x1 and y1 in one dataframe, then x2 and y2 in another. Pass the name of the dataframe you want to plot to the data argument in geom_point. This can be different for each call to geom_point

Comment: .. or append the vectors and use an indicator: `data.frame(x=c(x1,x2), y=c(y1, y2), id=c(rep("y1", times=length(y1)), rep("y2", times=length(y2))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it is said in the comments to the question, the error comes from the way the data.frame is created, with two columns of different lengths ([@AllanCameron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221474/multiple-datasets-normalized-in-a-scatterplot#comment111794646_63221474)). The solution proposed by [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221474/multiple-datasets-normalized-in-a-scatterplot#comment111794658_63221474), changed to include `x1` and `x2`, even avoids two calls to `geom_point`, one is enough.

```
set.seed(2020)

normalize <- function(y) {
  y - median(y)
}

x1  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
x2  <- seq(-3, 3, 0.10)
y1 <- normalize(pnorm(x1)-3)
y2 <- normalize(pnorm(x2))
n1 <- length(y1)
n2 <- length(y2)

df1 <- data.frame(x = c(x1, x2),
                  y = c(y1, y2), 
                  id = c(rep("y1", times = n1), rep("y2", times = n2))
                  )

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, color = id)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(y1 = "red", y2 = "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: OK, I guess I need to let that sink in a bit :) Especially the id to color mapping part with the scale_color_manual I find a bit unexpected. But may I add another facet to the question? You are using x1 and x2 for the data frame - what if y1 and y2 were just vectors? So there would be just an implicit index instead? (no x1, no x2)

Comment: @tcurdt; ggplot needs an `x` value; you can easily add one to your data with `x1 = seq_along(y1)` etc if you only have `y` vectors

Comment: Nice. I got it somewhat working https://gist.github.com/tcurdt/53fe026a6118e134ad640ffc64ba19d4 Just the color mapping is not so great as the names appearing in two different places.

Comment: @tcurdt I cannot reproduce the names appearing in two different places but if you have two aesthetics, for instance, `fill` and `color` in different geoms, try setting argument `show.legend = FALSE` in the geom you don't want the legend of. This is just a guess, though.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I meant also naming them in scale_color_manual. But I found a way around that. I just pass a palette into scale_colour_manual now. Thanks for the help!